# django shell - some querysets are empty in the shell but they shouldn't be

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I am using the django shell to look at some querysets.  I am able to retrieve all of my `Student` objects with `.all()` but if I then try to retrieve one object with `.get()` or filter on a field, I'm getting empty returns. The project seems to run ok on the browser (I'm still in the progress of writing all my tests but functionally it is working).  I am able to successfully use get() or filter on a field with my `Objective`model.

Here is what I get with `all()`:

```
>>> from gradebook.models import Student, Objective
>>> s = Student.objects.all()
>>> for i in s:
...     print(i.student_first)
...
 John
 Sally
 Keith
 Terrance
 Henry
 Analise
 Ron
>>>
```

Now if I try to use `get()`:

```
>>> qs = Student.objects.get(student_first='Analise')
Traceback (most recent call last):
gradebook.models.Student.DoesNotExist: Student matching query does not exist.
```

Or filter on a field:

```
>>> s.filter(student_first='Ron')
<QuerySet []>
>>>
```

Student model

```
class Student(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    student_first = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    student_last = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=31)
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    attend = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    student_number = models.IntegerField()
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.fullname
```

Comment: Do your strings have a leading space, so `' Analise'` instead of `'Analyse'`? What if you `print(repr(i.student_first))`.

Comment: Yes, you're correct.  There is a leading space. I need to figure out how those got there. Thanks.